# Internal images need of many resolutions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, resolution, image

The most of the responses that i saw are about buttons and icons, but and how about pictures?
I have several pictures in the database of my app and my question is, should i have many versions of each image (one for each resolution) or scale the pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scale the pictures can be a good approach, but you can store some format for caching and avoid cpu processing. you can't choose only one, you can combine.

Comment: OK, thanks for the rapid response. I will pay attention in my processing.

Answer (score 0):

For all the images used in your app bundle you really should provide @2x images these days. They just look so much cripsier....

As for images downloaded or kept in the database - at least for .png or .jpeg images - you can always take advantage of the info that they hold in their bellies. That's why the [scale property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW39) of `UIImage` is there for...

Comment: Right, i will study that property. Thanks for the different approach.